# Creating Topic Filter rule via CorrelationFilter with Azure Functions App

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I want to create filter rule via CorrelationFilter for subscriptions associated with a Topic, as it is faster than SQLFilter.

The rule: any message that contains a header that equals to a string will go to one subscription, another string will go to different subscription. For example:

```
Topic: order
Subcription1: header_orderType: orderPlaced
Subcription2: header_orderType: orderPaid
```

Similar to the one highlighted in blue below via Service Bus Explorer.

[image]
Below is other ways that can acheive that.

SQLFilter in code
https://dzone.com/articles/everything-you-need-know-about-5

SQLFilter
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters

PS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/New-AzureRmServiceBusRule?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 3):

The [TopicFilters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters) sample covers correlation filter too which is setup using an ARM template. The same should be possible in C# and PS as well.

#### C#

You will have to first create a [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.CorrelationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.correlationfilter?view=azure-dotnet) object

```cs
var orderPlacedFilter = new CorrelationFilter();

filter.Properties["header_orderType"] = "orderPlaced";
```

And then add it to your subscription client object by calling [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.addruleasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_SubscriptionClient_AddRuleAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Filter_)

```cs
subsClient.AddRuleAsync("orderPlacedFilter", orderPlacedFilter);
```

Similarly, for the other subscription and its filter.

#### PowerShell

> Guess the documentation isn't really great on this one but I believe this should work

```bsh
$rule = New-AzServiceBusRule -ResourceGroupName prvalav-common -Namespace prvalav-common -Topic test -Subscription test -Name SBRule -SqlExpression "test = 0"

$rule.FilterType = 1
$rule.SqlFilter = $null
$rule.CorrelationFilter.Properties["header_orderType"] = "orderPlaced"

Set-AzServiceBusRule -ResourceGroupName prvalav-common -Namespace prvalav-common -Topic test -Subscription test -Name SBRule -InputObject $rule
```

If you were wondering about the `FilterType = 1`, check the [`FilterType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.models.filtertype?view=azure-dotnet) enum.

**After setting this up**, in your function app, you would just use the [Service Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---configuration) with the topic/subscription details.

Comment: Great, this is very hard to find and really the only way to script a CorrelationFilter!